# How do I view non matching files only in fdupes?

Tags: files, duplicate-files

I understand how fdupes works to find and display duplicate files when comparing two directories, what I would like to know, is how to do the opposite, that is, display any and all *non* matching files in the output
can fdupes do this, or is there another program that can do it better?
(ps I need the comparisons to be made in the same way as fdupes, either with md5 sums, or with bitwise comparison between files)

Answer (score 2):

I've been thinking about adding this option to [rmlint](https://rmlint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for a while (but nobody had asked for it until now).  I've created a test branch which now has this option (https://github.com/SeeSpotRun/rmlint/tree/feature/uniques).

If you want to try it out, you will need to install as follows:

---

1. Install dependencies if you don't already have them:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install git scons python3-sphinx python3-nose gettext build-essential
$ sudo apt-get install libelf-dev libglib2.0-dev libblkid-dev libjson-glib-1.0 libjson-glib-dev
```

2. Grab the test branch source:

```bsh
$ cd ~
$ git clone -b feature/uniques https://github.com/SeeSpotRun/rmlint.git
$ cd rmlint/
```

3. Compile and (optionally) install:

```bsh
$ scons config
$ scons DEBUG=1 -j4
$ sudo scons DEBUG=1 -j4 --prefix=/usr install
$ # (if you skip the install step then replace 'rmlint' with './rmlint' below)
```

4. Find unique files (will not delete anything):

```bsh
$ # this will display unique files on your screen:
$ rmlint -o uniques path/to/your/files
$ # or use either of the following to write a list of unique files to unique.txt:
$ rmlint -o uniques:unique.txt path/to/your/files
$ rmlint -o uniques path/to/your/files > unique.txt
```

If you want a list of files in `dir2` that *don't* have a twin in `dir1` you can *tag* dir2 using `//` as a separator and add `-k` (or `--keep-all-tagged`) to the command:

```
$ rmlint -k -o uniques dir1 // dir2
```

(Note that if there are two identical files in dir2, but they don't have a copy in dir1, they will still get listed as "unique" in the last example)

5. Let us know how it went.
   Any problems or suggestions either reply here or at our [issues log](https://github.com/sahib/rmlint/issues)

---

Be aware that in the above examples, if you have two files with different names but the same content, they will *not* be flagged as unique.  If you *do* want them to be flagged as unique, add `-b` or `--match-basename` to the command line.

Regarding md5 sums etc: rmlint uses [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) by default, which is about 4 billion times stronger than md5.  You can upgrade this to [SHA-512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Comparison_of_SHA_functions) by adding `-p` to the command line, or you can do a byte-by-byte comparison instead by adding `-pp` (although this chews up a bit more RAM).

Comment: ... or if the directory structure is the same in both the directories you are comparing then you can use `rsync` in `dry-run` mode:  

`rsync -avc --dry-run dir2 dir1`
This will list files in dir2 if there is no corresponding file in dir2 with the same path, name and checksum.